# i want to recieve data from serial port and when i am recieveng it each data starts from the new line and i want the old data to be change by new one

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, serial-port

When recieving data from serial port in label it starts from a new line. I want the old data was replaced by a new one.

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        myPort = IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames()
        ComboBox1.Items.AddRange(myPort)

        closeButton.Enabled = False

    End Sub
 Private Sub SerialPort1_DataReceived(sender As System.Object, e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort1.DataReceived
        ReceivedText(SerialPort1.ReadExisting())
    End Sub
 Private Sub ReceivedText(ByVal [text] As String) 'input from ReadExisting
        If Me.Label1.InvokeRequired Then
            Dim x As New SetTextCallback(AddressOf ReceivedText)
            Me.Invoke(x, New Object() {(text)})
        Else
            Me.Label1.Text &= [text] 'append text
        End If
    End Sub
```

https://cloud.mail.ru/public/5qLo/5gHS6Pazw
here is screenshot

Comment: Screenshot gives a '404' error after a long pause.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the new data to replace the old data in your label text, isn't it just a case of removing the `&` from the line that appends it to the text, so it replaces instead?

I am not familiar with how the serial port reader sends data - you might have to build the incoming data into a buffer string, search for a new line and manually split the string, but that should be quite simple to do.